# how to show my hexo blog on google search

Tags: blogs, github-pages, hexo

I am using github pages and hexo to make my own blog. 
I wrote few articles and it looks find.(https://bmy4415.github.io/2018/05/08/ssh-key/)
(This site is written in Korean).

But I cannot search my blog on Google Search even if search as "bmy4415's note" which is my blog's main name.

I also used hexo plugin 'hexo-generator-seo-friendly-sitemap' and 'hexo-generator-search' but it seems not effective. Is there any additional setting that will show my blog on Google Search? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google does NOT know everything on its own.

Go to [Google webmasters` tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) and fill needed data and verify your web ownership. Googlebot will start visiting and tracking your site.

Plus have a look at robots.txt

Comment: @bmy4415 Glad to hear that! So please mark this as correct answer please

Comment: Sorry for late mark. I'm new to stackoverflow and did not know how to mark. Thanks!